# Gradle 4.6 + Junit 5: `-Dtest.single` doesn't work?

Tags: gradle, junit5

With Gradle 4.6, I made a super simple, test project to test JUnit 5 compatibility. It seems that `-Dtest.single` doesn't work. I've scoured the docs, I'd like to run a single test class and/or a single test method. Here, I expected

```
 gradle clean -Dtest.single=junittest.SampleTests test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Could not find matching test for pattern: junittest.SampleTests
```

I have a purposely failing test case named `failingTest()`:

```
gradle clean test

> Task :test FAILED

junittest.SampleTests > failingTest() FAILED
    org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError at SampleTests.java:16
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url "http://packages.confluent.io/maven/" }
}

test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
  options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
}

dependencies {
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0'
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering), the `test.single` option is based on file name patterns, i.e. when you replace `.` with `/`, it works:

```
./gradlew clean test -Dtest.single=junittest/SampleTests
```

However, using the `--tests` option is easier in most cases:

```
./gradlew clean test --tests junittest.SampleTests
```